# how to remove anchor tag and make it text

Tags: java, html

```
String k= <html>

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&

amp;id=1999033000019320&amp;path=/Notifications/DirectTaxLaws/HTMLFiles/S.O.193(E)30031999.htm&

amp;aa=">number S.O.I93(E), dated the 30th March, 1999
</html>
```

I'm getting this HTML in a `String` and I want to remove the anchor tag so that data is also removed from link.

I just want display it as text not as a link.

how to do this i m trying to do so much not able to do please send me code regarding that i m

creating app for Android this issue i m getting in android on web view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following example (don't remember where i've found it, but it works) using replace method to modify the string before showing it:

```
k = replace ( k, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=", "");


 String replace(String _text, String _searchStr, String _replacementStr) {
    // String buffer to store str
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    // Search for search
    int searchStringPos = _text.indexOf(_searchStr);
    int startPos = 0;
    int searchStringLength = _searchStr.length();
    // Iterate to add string
    while (searchStringPos != -1) {
        sb.append(_text.substring(startPos, searchStringPos)).append(_replacementStr);
        startPos = searchStringPos + searchStringLength;
        searchStringPos = _text.indexOf(_searchStr, startPos);
    }

    // Create string
    sb.append(_text.substring(startPos,_text.length()));

    return sb.toString();
}
```

To substitute all the target with an empty line:

```
    k = replace ( k, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=1999033000019320&amp;path=/Notifications/DirectTaxLaws/HTMLFiles/S.O.193(E)30031999.htm&amp;aa=\">", "");
```

No escape is needed for slash.

Comment: But i want to remove ""http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&id=1999033000019320&path=/Notifications/DirectTaxLaws/HTMLFiles/S.O.193(E)30031999.htm&aa=">"this one also

Comment: just play with replace method

Comment: plz help me i m not able to remove that..plz tell me clue

Comment: String k = replace ( desc, "  <a target=\"_blank\"  href= \"    http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdirecttaxlaws%2ffileopencontainer.aspx%3fPage%3dCIRNO%26id%3d1999033000019320%26path%3d%2fNotifications%2fDirectTaxLaws%2fHTMLFiles%2fS.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm%26aa%3d&Page=CIRNO&id=1999033000019320&path=/Notifications/DirectTaxLaws/HTMLFiles/S.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm&aa=  \"", "");

Comment: String k = replace ( desc, "  <a target=\"_blank\"  href= \"    http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdirecttaxlaws%2ffileopencontainer.aspx%3fPage%3dCIRNO%26id%3d1999033000019320%26path%3d%2fNotifications%2fDirectTaxLaws%2fHTMLFiles%2fS.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm%26aa%3d&Page=CIRNO&id=1999033000019320&path=/Notifications/DirectTaxLaws/HTMLFiles/S.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm&aa=  \"", "");

Comment: String k = replace ( desc, "  <a target=\"_blank\"  href= \"    http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdirecttaxlaws%2ffileopencontainer.aspx%3fPage%3dCIRNO%26id%3d1999033000019320%26path%3d%2fNotifications%2fDirectTaxLaws%2fHTMLFiles%2fS.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm%26aa%3d&Page=CIRNO&id=1999033000019320&path=/Notifications/DirectTaxLaws/HTMLFiles/S.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm&aa=  \"", "");

Comment: again linking coming when i m trying to replace wat ever i post in previous comment plz wat i m doing wrong???

Comment: rosco plz tell me how to escap i m trying to replac /  \b not \' but not found not change i m getting value but not replacing plz tell me code where i have to replace it

Comment: http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&amp;id=35000000000000001648&amp;search=

Comment: but id is differ href comes dynamically it varies id="......" how i ll set id values so that it take different id value?

Answer (score 3):

use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org), and `jSoup.parse()`

Comment: String k = replace ( desc, "  <a target=\"_blank\"  href= \"    http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdirecttaxlaws%2ffileopencontainer.aspx%3fPage%3dCIRNO%26id%3d1999033000019320%26path%3d%2fNotifications%2fDirectTaxLaws%2fHTMLFiles%2fS.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm%26aa%3d&Page=CIRNO&id=1999033000019320&path=/Notifications/DirectTaxLaws/HTMLFiles/S.O.193%28E%2930031999.htm&aa=  \"", ""); i m trying to replacebut again liking is coming